# Фото галерея на PHP

Tags: php, html, css, javascript

Я пишу для себя фото галерею на PHP и столкнулся с такой проблемой: в одном блоке DIV у меня выводит список превью фотоглафий, мне их нужно вывести в соседний DIV в увеличеном размере. Как мне это сделать ? (Предпочтительнее на чистом PHP,CSS, но можно и простенький JS)

P.S. пытался сделать в стилях через Hover и Active но безрезультатно( картинка просто сдвигается внутри своего блока и пропадает за его границами.

Пример - http://jsfiddle.net/NM5Fk/

Comment: Разместите пример на jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NM5Fk/ Воть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот **[тут](http://www.tobypitman.com/pure-css-sliding-image-gallery/)** можно посмотреть, как сделать галерею с помощью только **css**.
Рабочий пример на js можно посмотреть вот тут: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/jcjuk/)**

Абстрактный пример на основе вашей разметки и стилей:

**html:**

```
<div class="left2">
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_1.jpg" />
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_2.jpg" />
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_3.jpg">
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_4.jpg" />
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_5.jpg" />
    <img class="miniimg" onmouseover="show(this);" onmouseout="hide(this);" alt="art" src="картинка_6.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="fullsize" class="content"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.left2 {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    min-height:450;
    max-height:550px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
}
.content {
    border:1px solid black;
    display: none;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin:25px 0px 20px 50px;
    width:200px;
}
.miniimg {
    margin-top:3px;
    max-width:70%;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
  function show(img) {
      var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
      fullsize.style.display = "block";
      fullsize.innerHTML = "<img class='bigimg' src='" + img.src + "' alt='fullsize' width='200' height='200' />";
  }

  function hide(img) {
      var fullsize = document.getElementById("fullsize");
      fullsize.style.display = "none";
      fullsize.innerHTML = "";
  }
```

Comment: В JS вообще не шарю пока что, но с этим разобрался, а как можно модифицировать код, что бы при первом нажатии на миниатюру - появлялось большое изображение, а при повторном нажатии на мини - исчезало ? )